# Most Elegant way to dismiss a presentModalViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I have successfully shown a view upon launch that authenticates a user. Upon success, I want the presentModalViewController to no longer be visible and deallocate properly.

My code is as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

    Overview *overview = [[Overview alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overview" bundle:nil];
    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:overview animated:YES];
    [overview release];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In your modal viewcontroller you need a piece of code doing:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer. The modally displayed viewController will pass this message on to the viewController that has originally opened the modal-view.

Comment: @Till is it always the case? in apple's music picker and e-mail sending classes, a delegate message will be sent to the viewController that opened it, which will than decide whether it dismisses or does something else, based on the input on the modal view controller.

Comment: @Zaky it is always the case when talking about using the methods [UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] and [UIViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:] according to Apple's references.

Comment: @Zaky that is dependent on the design of your program, but functionally speaking you can do it either in the ViewController class itself or somewhere else. Putting it inside the ViewController however limits its use. This implies that the ViewController always will be shown and dismissed modally. If you were to reuse the ViewController somewhere else (for instance in a NavigationController) that code wouldn't make sense. That's why from a design point of view it is better to externalize the call (as in the Apple examples), but it is  more work, you need a delegate + protocol etc.